# How can I provide a set of events to calendar applications as internet-calendar?

Tags: calendar, icalendar, webdav, webcal

I would like to share dates maintained in my web app via an API so they can be automatically imported and/or synchronized to a calendar application.

In many calendar applications, in terms of calendar viewers/editors (e.g. Outlook with CalDAV Synchronizer Plugin), there is an option to import/integrate/subscribe to an online calendar (the content) by providing an URL (e.g. from Owncloud).

I would like to provide such an option to users of my web application. It should be possible to add events that are maintained in the web application to the users calendar application and also make it reflect changes to the events (e.g. moved to different date or deleted). The current requirement is one-way read-only, it is not necessary to be able to write back changes made in the calendar application to the web application.

The solution is not a one-time calendar download. If events change or new events are added, I want this to be reflected in the calendar application.

Specific questions:

- Which technology or standard should be used to maximize compatibility with calendar applications?
- Which packages or libraries can be used to implement the web application part (Node.js/Nest.js)?

I have tried to search for a solution on the web hoping to find a tutorial, but all I can find is tools to read calendars or tutorials to build a calendar viewer..

I believe the solution is probably related to WebDAV and/or iCalendar (ics) files.